# Limit character length after specific word in R

Tags: regex, r

I have vector of names that I would like to clean. I would like to shorten each character length:

Example:

```
x <- c("LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording), LambM, abc , a.b.c",
       "LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording)")
```

I would like to obtain in this example only the first `LambMa a.b.c.` and cut off the rest. So if the specific character doesn't contain the `a.b.c.` twice DO NOTHING (skip).

So the specific word or expression to look for is `"a.b.c"`. so cut the rest after first occurrence.

EDIT: I would like to obtain only the characters before `a.b.c.` (included) from vector `x` in case the there is double occurrence of `a.b.c.` in that given character string `x`.

The solution to the example above would be:

```
solution <- c("LambMa, a.b.c.","LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording)")
```

EDIT 2: Also partial solution would be very helpful and would be accepted. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite follow what you are asking. Can you provide the expected output for your example?

Comment: Why is your sample solution re-ordered from the input?.  BTW, if your 'names' are always comma-separated, I'd recommend using `strsplit` to break the line in to a vector of values and working with that.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Re-ordered? Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. The first part of the solution is just all the inputs before a.b.c. (included) and the second stays intact since there is no double entry of a.b.c.

Comment: The problem is that some do not contain commas, or not so many commas (or on other places as set example). I thought commas can be ignored altogether. What matters is the `a.b.c.` and all before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to swap out if the pattern you specified matches. To avoid using a look-behind, you can capture the first `a.b.c.` and replace with it:

```
gsub("(a\\.b\\.c\\.).+(a\\.b\\.c)","\\1",x)
[1] "LambMa, a.b.c."                        
[2] "LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording)"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording), LambM, abc , a.b.c",
       "LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording)") 

occ_abc<-gregexpr("a.b.c",x) # find the occurences of "a.b.c."
for(i in 1:length(occ_abc)){ # for each item of x
    if(length(occ_abc[[i]])>=2) { # if there is 2 or more occurences
      x[i]<-substr(x[i],1,occ_abc[[i]][1]+5) # replace with first part of the string
    } else { # else leave the item untouched
      x[i]
    }
}
```

`>x`

```
[1] "LambMa, a.b.c."                         "LambMa, a.b.c., LaMa (shorter wording)"
```

The `if...else`part can very probably be replaced by an `ifelse`statement.

Comment: Thanks, it works on example but not on "real" data. However the solution provides what has been asked for. So if no one else provides better answer I will accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: @Max, what are your "real" data like ? If you provide data more like your "real" one, I can try and adapt my code...

Comment: @Max, you can make my code more general if you put `search_char<-"a.b.c"`, replace `a.b.c.` by `search_char` in the assignation of `occ_abc` and `5` by `nchar(search_char)-1` in the `if` instructions... Then of course `search_char`can be anything